# Is it possible to create an index that is built at insert time, as opposed to query time?

Tags: couchdb

I'm using CouchDB on Raspberry Pi 3.  My use case:

Collect sensor data coming from multiple sources with multi-process python app, capturing timestamp at the time of collection.  Because of the multiple threads, this data if serialized is regularly out of order.  I would like to put the data into some data structure so that it can be quickly ordered and have another process pick up the data in near real time for further processing.

My problem is that (using CouchDB), my view that builds an index on the timestamp is only created at read time, and it takes a long time to build.  What I'm looking for is index behavior from RDBMS where it rebuilds the index as data is inserted.  This way while each batch of insert would take a bit longer to insert, at least it's available quickly for the next process.

I have also considered Mongo but I don't like the 2GB limit on RPi.  Also considering SQLite3 but prefer the schemaless nature of NoSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation would be to set up some scheduled job (maybe via cron?) that [queries your view](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/ddoc/views.html#querying-views-and-indexes) and passes `stale=update_after`. The request itself will be very fast, because the view is not being calculated at query-time, but instead will happen asynchronously.

This is the pattern I've seen recommended that tries to avoid huge penalties for the first user to query a view, and should work pretty well here imo. When you query the view and need real-time results, you can omit the `stale` parameter.